# Different latitude and longitude using google maps and ggmap geocode function

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I am trying to plot the nearest Walmart store in Canada to a certain post code using **ggmap**. The function used to get the location is:

```
goodPoint<-geocode("M1L2K1 walmart canada")
```

This returned the lat and lon:

```
> goodPoint
       lon      lat
1    -79.30113  43.72304
```

When I check Google map search using the same search term and get the latitude and longitude I get 43.728933,-79.29565.

The difference between the returned latitude and longitude is about 1.1 km, so quite significant.

Can anyone suggest why there is this difference when in [the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf) it states that it uses Google Maps for the location? Any suggestions for ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the actual output from Google geocoder? The geocoder is not the same thing as the *maps search*. The geocoder resolves *addresses*, but it afaict does not perform searches such as "find a walmart near M1L2K1 canada".

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=M1L2K1%20walmart%20canada&sensor=false

yields the following parsed address:

> `"formatted_address" : "Scarborough, Ontario M1L 2K1, Kanada"
>
>   ...
>
>   "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
>
>   ...
>
>   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]`

So in fact, Google even tells you that this is a "postal code resolution" geocoding.

Again, geocoding does not equal search. "Walmart" is not a postal address, but a reasonable search term.